# Javascript - Regex for letters,numbers,underscore comma-seperated tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to regex and javascript and I was wondering if anyone knew what the regex would be for detecting whether or not if an input field contained the following type of format:

At least one alphanumeric and underscore( _ ) tag which can't contain spaces (e.g "test" and "test_" but not "test test")

Each tag seperated by a single comma (e.g "word1,word2,word_3, _word_4" but not "word1,,word2,word_3, _word_4) and any others symbos to be invalid (like ;!"'@#%^&*()-+=.>

An example of what I mean is this, these would be valid tags:

something1,something_2,something_something,something
And these would be invalid tags:

something1%,something%*2^,*!something%_&something,(*)something@+

It should also be able to accept just a single tag, as multiples tags too!!

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: thanks. i had already saw this!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you want to accept both uppercase and lowercase characters:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(,[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*$
```

The mentioned site has great information about regular expressions, I recommend reading through it. For now a short explanation:

`^` means beginning of the string, so that no other (possibly invalid) characters can precede it. Between `[` and `]` is a character class: specifying what characters may follow. `[ABC]` for example means an A, a B or a C. You can also specify ranges like `[A-E]`, which means an A, B, C, D or E.

In the regular expression above I specify the range `a` to `z`, `A` to `Z` (uppercase), `0` to `9` and the single character `_`. The `+` means that the character, a group or a character from the character class preceding it must appear at least once or more.

The `(` and `)` group a part of the regular expression. In this case they group the `,` (for the comma-separated list you wanted) and a repetition of the expression so far. The `*` means (like the `+`) that the group preceding it may appear many times, but with the difference that the `*` makes it optional.

**So, in short:** this expression allows tags consisting of at least one or more characters in the range *a-z*, *A-Z*, *0-9* or the character `_`, optionally followed by more tags that begin with a `,`, specifying the requirements for a comma-separated list :)

Answer (score 1):

A single tag would be matched by

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]+
```

This is a character class containing Latin letters in upper- and lowercase as well as digits and the underscore. This can usually be shortened to

```
\w+
```

if you know that your RE engine won't handle Unicode (this is the case for JavaScript). I'll continue with `\w+` for now, though.

You can match multiple tags by selecting a single tag and a possibly zero number of *comma* + *tag*:

```
\w+(,\w+)*
```

If you want to validate a complete string, you should put anchors for *start of string* and *end of string* around the expression:

```
^\w+(,\w+)*$
```

Comment: basicly i've already try this: 

/^[a-zA-Z0-9_,α-ωΑ-Ω0-9_]+\,[a-zA-Z0-9_,α-ωΑ-Ω0-9_]/ 

which accepts lettes(english and greeks),numbers,underscore only if i give two or more tags and gives me error if i give just a single tag.(it works fine and gives me error for any other symbol which it's that i want)